# Seperating Parts of a file name in a Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell-script

If I have a file in the format of `./AAAA_AAAA_00_00_AAA-22222.txt`, how would I be able to split it into `AAAA_AAAA_00_00_AAA` and `22222`?

Comment: By separate you mean adding a space?

Comment: i mean having them as separate strings

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. Dou you mean two files with the two separate strings?

Comment: Like if I have the file name, I want to seperate it into seperate strings, like ./AAAA_AAAA_00_00_AAA-22222.txt is first = AAAA_AAAA_00_00_AAA second = 22222

Answer (score 2):

```
$ filename=./AAAA_AAAA_00_00_AAA-22222.log
$ filename=$(basename "$filename" .log) # remove `./` and `.log`
$ echo "${filename}"
AAAA_AAAA_00_00_AAA-22222
$ echo "${filename%%-*}"
AAAA_AAAA_00_00_AAA
$ echo "${filename##*-}"
22222
```

- `${parameter##word}` removes the longest prefix pattern
- `${parameter%%word}` removes the longest suffix pattern

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (bash manual)